# PowerShell change color of output

Tags: powershell

The condition does not work, always "else"

```
Get-Process| Select-Object Name,VM | 
ForEach { 
if ($_.Name -eq "chrome") { [console]::ForegroundColor="red"; $_; } 
else { [console]::ForegroundColor="white"; $_; }  
[console]::ForegroundColor="white"; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Write-Host` instead, running `[console]::ForegroundColor` changes the color of all foreground text, basically all text that's not Verbose or Error Stream.  However, you can change each line if you use `Write-Host` instead.

```
Get-Process msedge,notepad++,chrome | Select-Object Name | 
ForEach { 
    if ($_.Name -eq "chrome") { 
    write-host -ForegroundColor red $_.Name
        } 
    elseif ($_.Name -eq "msedge"){ 
    write-host -ForegroundColor green $_.Name; 
    }
    else{
    write-host -ForegroundColor white $_.Name; 
    }

}
```

And the output:

[image]